# How does Java method reference String::compareTo implementing Comparator<String> works?

Tags: java, methods

```
java.util.Comparator<String> lambda = (s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2); // line 1
java.util.Comparator<String> methodRef = String::compareTo;         // line 2
```

I can't understand why line 2 works without error, and why it is equivalent to line 1. Line 2 is returning a method reference that receives a string and returns and int (i.e. `int compare(String s)` ), however, comparator functional method signature is `int compare(T o1, T o2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ref to `String::compareTo` is a special kind of method reference called ["Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

In this case, the compiler knows that we are referencing a not-static method of a given class, and it can translate to a functional interface with the desired signature.

For example:

```java
String t1 = "t1";
String t2 = "t2";

// this
Comparator<String> comparator = String::compareTo;
comparator.compareTo(t1, t2);

// will be 'translated' to:
Comparator<String> comparator = (String s1, String s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2);
t1.compareTo(t2);
```

> Note that the method will be called with the context of the first parameter (the this used will be `t1`).

Points 8 and 9 of [State of lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) give a rationale for this implementation.

From [Overview of method references](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bykHgnNXuA) youtube video

[image: Overview of method references]